# ASP.net - Simple list all users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-profiles

Given a profile field I store with each user the following way:

```
Context.Profile.SetPropertyValue("IsSubscribed", isSubscribed.Checked);
Context.Profile.Save();
```

How would I on another page fetch all users email addresses where `isSubscribed = true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        List<String> subscribedEmails = new List<String>();

        ProfileInfoCollection profiles = ProfileManager.GetAllProfiles(ProfileAuthenticationOption.All);

        foreach (ProfileInfo profileInfo in profiles)
        {
            ProfileBase profile = ProfileBase.Create(profileInfo.UserName);
            if ((bool)profile.GetPropertyValue("IsSubscribed"))
            {
                subscribedEmails.Add((string)profile.GetPropertyValue("Email"));
            }
        }
```

Edit: To get the user's email address from the membership system use:

```
subscribedEmails.Add(Membership.GetUser(profileInfo.UserName).Email);
```

Comment: Super answer thank you!  But the email is stored with the membership system I think, how do I access this?  The email isn't a property associated with the profile system

Comment: Hmm it's also not seeming to return records at all when the value definatly is true...

Comment: I am not sure why it isn't returning records for you. Are you using a custom profile provider?

Comment: Isn't this generating a request for EACH user in the database (to retrieve each profile, one by one) ?